# Laravel: How to prevent overwritten .htaccess code while hitting website?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

While running my website, .htaccess file is resetting or overriding with new code. New code is replaced my own code, so that i cant redirect the url.

I have changed the permission of htaccess file as readable format.  After changed the permission also, the htaccess file is overriding.

This is my code :

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off    
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

New code replaced by htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Why you not redirect using Laravel Route ?

Comment: Is it possible to redirect a domain name using the laravel route?

Comment: It's possible, check docs here [Laravel Redirects](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects). Simple try `return redirect('http://example.com/');`